# Is the axiom of choice used to order the orbits of the truncation function through periodic 2-adic numbers using their Lyndon words?

Tags: logic, set-theory, axiom-of-choice

Let $X$ be the periodic two adic integers.

Let $f$ be the truncation function, i.e. $f(x)=(x-1)/2$ for odd numbers and $x/2$ for even.

Let $X/f$ be the set of transitive orbits of $f$ in $X$

These orbits are in bijection with the base $2$ Lyndon words.  Obtain the bijection by taking the repeating periodic part, and rotating its digits until it is its Lyndon word.

Let the orbits $X/f$ be ordered by the lexicographical order on their Lyndon words.

Have I used the axiom of choice here?

**Motivation**

I'm trying to prove a problem which I know requires the axiom of choice and I'd like to save myself from attempting with methods which lack the required firepower.

I also have a hunch I might need a more complex ordering than lexicographical - one which reflects the magnitude of the infinite repeating sum, and I doubt that corresponds with the lexicographical order.

Comment: @MikhailKatz that wouldn't truncate a 2-adic number. Say you have $\overline011_2=3$ then $f$ truncates it to $\overline01_2=1$ via the function $x\mapsto(x-1)/2$. I'm curious why you thought $3$?